# including an iterator in c++ vector construction

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In the code below, which is supposed to be an implementation of ranges::rotate:

```
auto second(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator new_first) -> std::vector<int>::const_iterator {
  auto copy = std::vector<int>(v.begin(), new_first);
  v.erase(v.begin(), new_first);
  return v.insert(v.end(), copy.begin(), copy.end());
}
```

what is actually happening in the first 2 lines of the function where the new_first iterator isn't necessarily at the end? I've only seen examples where the second parameter is specifically at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the arguments to the function look like this:

```
v : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
  new_first ^
```

Then this line:

```
auto copy = std::vector<int>(v.begin(), new_first);
```

uses the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `vector` that takes 2 iterators to construct the `copy` variable:

```
v : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
  new_first ^
copy : {1, 2}
```

Then this line:

```
v.erase(v.begin(), new_first);
```

uses the [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) method of `vector` to remove the initial elements:

```
v : { 3, 4, 5}
copy : {1, 2}
```

And finally, this line:

```
return v.insert(v.end(), copy.begin(), copy.end());
```

uses the [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) method of `vector` to copy the initial elements (stored in `copy`), to the end of `v`, and returns an iterator to the first inserted element:

```
v : { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 }
        return ^
```

effectively implementing `rotate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto copy = std::vector<int>(v.begin(), new_first);
```

You are copying first `new_first - v.begin()` elements to a new vector named `copy`.

```
v.erase(v.begin(), new_first);
```

You are erasing the same `new_first - v.begin()` elements from the original vector.

```
v.insert(v.end(), copy.begin(), copy.end());
```

You are inserting all the elements of `copy` into the original vector. So basically you've rotated the vector `v` to the right by `new_first - v.begin()` elements.

Therefore, if your v was `{1,2,3,4,5}` in the beginning and new_first points to say `4`, then the return vector is `{4,5,1,2,3}`